# Burp : Data is read from document.location and passed to $() via the following statements

Tags: xss, burp

How to deal with this code ?
Data is read from document.location and passed to $() via the following statements:

```
 var url =  document.location.toString();
 $('.nav-tabs a[href="#' + url.split('#')[1] + '"]').tab('show');
```

Comment: Are you trying to exploit it or defend it?

Comment: Trying to defend as its showing in BURP report..

Answer (score 0):

The question is this case would be what could come after the # in the URL. Most browsers will URL-encode special chars, but there may still be ways to get around it, especially in legacy browsers.

Regardless of that, I think it's a good idea to validate data before you use it. If you can restrict the accepted values to let's say a-z (and possibly numbers and dashes), there shouldn't be a way to exploit it.

```
var tab =  document.location.toString().split('#')[1];
if (tab && !/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/.test(tab)) $('.nav-tabs a[href="#' + tab + '"]').tab('show');
```